# 16.04 Can I get the old Unity thumb overlay scrollbar back?

Tags: overlay-scrollbars, scrollbar

Some people are hating the old overlay scrollbar, but I really like it as it gives me a good area to drag the scrollbar. The new thicker strip scrollbar is thinner than that on Windows and I find it harder to grip with my mouse.

I would like to achieve the following effect:

[image]

Is there still a chance to recover this feature?

*I hope they can re-add this feature to Unity, perhaps add an option for users to choose.*